# How to calculate the number of string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I retrieve a response from backend and want to calculate how much `admin_status` that I have . not character. One `admin_status` in service[0] is treated as 1. if have service[1] will assume as 2 as a total.

my response like this.

[image]

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.result == "success"){
        console.log(response)
        $.each(response.service, function (k, v1){
            if (v1.admin_status == 'admin-up' || v1.admin_status == 'UP'){
                console.log('up')

                var abc = v1.admin_status; // tr
                console.log(abc) // I get 'admin_status'

                console.log(abc.length) // I get 10 (total character, i dont want like this)
            }
            if (v1.admin_status == 'admin-down' || v1.admin_status == 'DOWN'){
                console.log('down')
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#total_serv").text("N/A");
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
if (v1.operate_status == 'operate-up' || v1.operate_status == 'UP'){
    const totalSvcUp = response.service.reduce((sum, obj) =>
    sum + ("operate_status" in obj ? 1 : 0), 0)
    $("#total_serv_up").text(totalSvcUp)
}
else if (v1.operate_status == 'operate-down' || v1.operate_status == 'DOWN'){
    const totalSvcDown = response.service.reduce((sum2, obj2) =>
    sum2 + ("operate_status" in obj2 ? 1 : 0), 0)
    $("#total_serv_down").text(totalSvcDown)
}
```

Comment: I think you retrive from `response.service.length`. is this right? or other logic. I understand as in the response, you got `service` array return, so you can get this from `service` array length.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *reduce* operation to produce a sum

```js
// this is just for the demo
const response = {
  service: [{
    admin_status: "admin-up",
    id: "foo"
  }, {
    admin_status: "admin-down",
    id: "bar"
  }, {
    not_admin_status: "nope",
    id: "baz"
  }]
}

const adminStatusCount = response.service.reduce((sum, obj) =>
  sum + ("admin_status" in obj ? 1 : 0), 0)
  
console.log(adminStatusCount)
```

---

To clarify the arguments and operation of [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)...

```js
const initialSumValue = 0

const callback = function(currentSum, obj) {
  if ("admin_status" in obj) {
    return currentSum + 1 // add one
  }
  return currentSum // add nothing
}

const adminStatusCount = response.service.reduce(callback, initialSumValue)
```

Comment: sorry I am new on this things, may I know what is `, 0)` at the end.

Comment: btw, thanks this solution solve my problem. already accept your answer.

Comment: That's the initial value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Hi, i just apply your code for the first value for id `total_serv_up` is appear, but for `total_serv_down` is nothing show even number 0. i just udpate the code above in `UPDATE` section.

Comment: maybe you can share both result, the previous and the new. So I can learn the differences.

Comment: If you don't even get a `0`, then the code isn't entering your `if (v1.operate_status == 'operate-down' || v1.operate_status == 'DOWN')` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to get all the items that admin_status and just check the length of output array:

```js
var input = [
  {admin_status: '1'},
  {},
  {admin_status: '1'},
  {},
  {admin_status: '1'}
];
console.log(input.filter(x => x.admin_status).length);

// or using formal function

var admin = input.filter(function(item) {
  return item.admin_status;
});

console.log(admin.length);
```

This works because if there are no admin_status it will be falsy value and if there is anything in that field it will be considered true for `filter`.